# Mqtt broker is not getting connected to angular app with ng2-mqtt library

Tags: angular, websocket, mqtt, paho

I have an angular app and node.js backend where a mqtt broker is running.
Broker is up and running and i can see the data in Mqtt Lens.

Now I want to subscribe to connect and subscribe to that mqtt broker in angular.

I have a basic code in app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Paho} from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'BMS';
  private client;
  mqttbroker = '105.221.215.112';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(this.mqttbroker, Number(7455), 'AHU_client');
    this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this);
    this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost.bind(this);
    this.client.connect({onSuccess: this.onConnect.bind(this)});
  }

  onConnect() {
    console.log('onConnect');
    this.client.subscribe('Unilever');
  }

  onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log('onConnectionLost:' + responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
  }

  onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log('onMessageArrived: ' + message.destinationName + ': ' + message.payloadString);  
  }
}
```

But the connection is not happening. And nothing is being printed in the console too. Can someone help me with why is the connection not happening?

Comment: Does the broker support MQTT over websockets on that port? (Also a hard coded client id is not a good idea)

Comment: I have the broker code but I have not written it, how do I check if it supports? Thanks

Comment: You should know how you've configured your broker. Which broker are you using?